# Uploading multiple documents to couchdb giving error

Tags: curl, couchdb

I have to upload `bulk document` into couchdb but this is not working and giving error. This is what i try to do with curl

```
curl -d '{"docs":[{"key":"baz","name":"bazzel"},{"key":"bar","name":"barry"}]}' -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/testdb/_bulk_docs
```

This is the error which comes for this

```
{"error":"bad_content_type","reason":"Content-Type must be application/json"}
```

This curl command is simple copy+paste from wiki of couchdb so ideally this should not be giving error. Is there anything that i am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the Header Content-Type application/json to your curl command. The flag is `-H`

e.g.

`curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"docs":[{"key":"baz","name":"bazzel"},{"key":"bar","name":"barry"}]}' -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/testdb/_bulk_docs`