# How to upload multiple documents with multiple JSON files to Cloudant DB via cURL?

Tags: json, api, curl, couchdb, cloudant

Currently I am able to PUT a single json file to a document in Cloudant using this : `curl -X PUT 'https://username.cloudant.com/dummydb/doc3' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @numbers.json`.I have many JSON files to be uploaded as different documents in the same DB.How can it be done?

Comment: Not of much help. Found reference to my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938435/uploading-multiple-documents-to-couchdb-giving-error but no solution yet . The "docs" in my case are .json files.How do I post them as Documents? @imseth

Comment: Do you want to use CURL or can you use other programming techniques, like Node.js?

Answer (score 4):

So you *definitely* want to use Cloudant's `_bulk_docs` API endpoint in this scenario. It's more efficient (and cost-effective) if you're doing a bunch of writes. You basically `POST` an array that contains all your JSON docs. Here's the documentation on it: https://docs.cloudant.com/document.html#bulk-operations

Going one step further, so long as you've structured your JSON file properly, you can just upload the file to `_bulk_docs`. In cURL, that would look something like this: `curl -X POST -d @file.json <domain>/db/_bulk_docs ...` (plus the content type and all that other verbose stuff).

One step up from that would be using the `ccurl` (CouchDB/Cloudant cURL) tool that wraps your cURL statements to Cloudant and makes them less verbose. See https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/2015/10/19/command-line-tools-for-cloudant-and-couchdb/ from https://stackoverflow.com/users/4264864/glynn-bird for more.

Happy Couching!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `for loop` and create documents from each JSON file.

For example, in the command below I have 4 JSON files in my directory and I create 4 documents in my `people` database:

```
for file in *.json
> do
> curl -d @$file https://username:password@myinstance.cloudant.com/people/ -H "Content-Type:application/json"
> done
{"ok":true,"id":"763a28122dad6c96572e585d56c28ebd","rev":"1-08814eea6977b2e5f2afb9960d50862d"}
{"ok":true,"id":"763a28122dad6c96572e585d56c292da","rev":"1-5965ef49d3a7650c5d0013981c90c129"}
{"ok":true,"id":"763a28122dad6c96572e585d56c2b49c","rev":"1-fcb732999a4d99ab9dc5462593068bed"}
{"ok":true,"id":"e944282beaedf14418fb111b0ac1f537","rev":"1-b20bcc6cddcc8007ef1cfb8867c2de81"}
```